# How do I find all links in a page and add check boxes after them in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I know how to find all the links but I do not know how to programmatically inject html after a tag. I think the html should end up like this:

`<a href="http:www.google.com> this is a useful website</a> <input type="checkbox" name="option" >`

Comment: -1 as the question does not show any research effort. Where is the current code you have tried with the code you are currently using to select all links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this simply in JQuery, using  [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$("a").after("<input type='checkbox' name='option' />");
```

**Edit**

Inspired by RobG's comment -- to apply to only specific links, change the selector:

```
// select all a-tags that link to Google
$("a[href='http://www.google.com']")
```

Or use a wildcard of some kind:

```
// select all a-tags that contain any href tags (ie, exclude anchor tags)
$("a[href]")
```

Comment: Not all A elements are links, some are anchors.

Comment: @RobG: While you are absolutely correct, OP has not given much detail to determine if they are or not. The selector should obviously take scope into account if possible. OP also stated `I know how to find all the links` so we assume OP can add `after()` to the result :)

Comment: Just need to add an appropriate selector to @dbaseman's answer, like $('a[href^⁼"http"]')

Comment: +1 for the alternative but as OP stated he already knew how to select them but +1 for completeness.

Comment: @Roimer—why do the extra work when there is a collection ready to go? I would have expected `$(document.links)`. Not all href values start with "http".

Answer (score 3):

Or you can do this with plain JavaScript (though jQuery definitely simplifies your task):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
    var chk = document.createElement('input');
    chk.type = 'checkbox';
    chk.value = links[i].textContent || links[i].innerText; // or whatever...
    chk.name = chk.value.replace(/(\s+)/g, ''); // or whatever...
    links[i].parentNode.insertBefore(chk, links[i].nextSibling);
}
```

If, as raised in the comment to [dbaseman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13674706/82548), you're using some of the `a` elements as anchors, you should consider using `id`s on existing elements as the targets for internal navigation, since an empty, though named, `a` is a pretty old technique, and even IE supports the use of `id`s now.

However if change is not possible the above can be changed to incorporate an `if` check:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var i = 0, len = links.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (links[i].href) {
        var chk = document.createElement('input');
        chk.type = 'checkbox';
        chk.value = links[i].textContent || links[i].innerText; // or whatever...
        chk.name = chk.value.replace(/(\s+)/g, ''); // or whatever...
        links[i].parentNode.insertBefore(chk, links[i].nextSibling);
    }
}
```

Further, if you wish to refine the `a` elements to those contained within a given element, simply use a specific node in place of `document` in the first line:

```
var links = document.getElementById('onlyInThisElement').getElementsByTagName('a');
```

Where first you retrieve the node with an `id` of `onlyInThisElement` and then search only within that `div` for the `a` elements.

Comment: `If, as you suggest in your comment to dbaseman's answer you're using some of the a elements as anchors, ` That was RobG who suggested the possiblity. OP has given no info on that except `I know how to find all the links` which would imply that is the part not required as a solution.

Comment: You should be using `insertBefore` with `nextSibling`, there is no `insertAfter`.

Comment: @RobG: I think I confused my intent (since I was using `nextSibling`) with the method's name. *Sigh* ...I should probably avoid the cider prior to attempting to post code. XD

Comment: @DavidThomas—yes, it's a bit counter intuitive. +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the links in a page using the [links](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-7068919) collection. You can then easily append a checkbox by looping over the collection and using [insertBefore](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-952280727) and [nextSibling](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-6AC54C2F) or whatever jQuery equivalent you wish to use.

Note that the links collection only includes A elements with a HREF attribute, it will not include anchors (i.e. A elements with a NAME or ID an no HREF).